# Skype4Sharp.Exceptions.InvalidSkypeActionException: 'Not signed in'

Tags: c#, skype

I'm using Skype4Sharp.dll to make call. [So I've tried the code here.](https://github.com/lin-e/Skype4Sharp/blob/master/Skype4Sharp/ExampleBot/Program.cs) But it stops at  `mainSkype.StartPoll();` and says `Skype4Sharp.Exceptions.InvalidSkypeActionException: 'Not signed in'.`

Any suggestion?   Thanks in advance.

Here is the console output I get after running the code
[image]

Comment: And are you signed in? Is your "USERNAME", "PASSWORD" correct?

Comment: @rudolf_franek yes,it's correct.